# How can I connect a community connector (apps script) to a GA4 property so that it functions like it did with Advanced services and UA?

Tags: google-oauth, urlfetch, google-analytics-4

I am currently trying to connect a community connector (apps script) to GA4 in order to retrieve data and modify it before sending it to data studio. I have done this for Universal Analytics properties easily with advanced services; However, Since the Advanced services Analytics option does not work for GA4 properties I have been looking into retrieving data from analytics using fetchUrl. I am wondering if this is the best/only way to connect to GA4?

I have received input for my current code (basic fetchUrl code) which suggested that I would need to access the cloud api for authentication. Now I am wondering if I actually have to do these extra steps to connect to a google source from app script? The reason why I am unsure is because supermetrics has a GA4 connector which does not require any extra steps and of course connects to a GA4 property with a simple authentication method. I would like to essentially create that same connection in app script. Any advice would also be appreciated.

Also I would love to hear if there is any information on when we can expect advanced services to work for GA4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you will need to use the new [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1), however in this moment it is an early preview version of the API and is subject to change.

I don't know what the supermetrics plugin does specifically, however i recommend to **link the automatic export of GA4 data in BigQuery and connect to it**.

Google has not released any deadline for the release of this advanced service. I believe that before this it will have to make this whole new system stable since every week it undergoes updates and adjustments.